# Why are my two modals on the same page triggering each others validate?

Tags: asp.net

Pretty new to asp.net. So I just wanted to have multiple modals on my page, like I can do it in HTML. But the problem here is, that the first modal of the code works fine. But the second modal triggers on submit all of the RequiredFieldValidators of the first modal, and doesn't fire it's own function on the code behind (eventEintragen()). The function exists thats for sure.

I searched trough my whole code and checked every call. It has to be a problem with the modals itself, i'm guessing I missunderstood smth about asp.net and got both of the modals in conflict with each others. I would be gratefull for some help... Of course I looked into some other questions, but as you can guess, it's pretty hard to find someone with the same conflict problem.

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
    </asp:ScriptManager>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
                Event erstellen
            </button>
            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <!--Modal-->
                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
                    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                        <div class="modal-dialog">
                            <div class="modal-content">
                                <div class="modal-header">
                                    <h5 class="modal-title">Modal title</h5>
                                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                    </button>
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-body">
                                    <asp:ValidationSummary runat="server" CssClass="text-danger" />
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="Wettkampfname" placeholder="Wettkampfname" CssClass="form-control" TextMode="SingleLine" />
                                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ControlToValidate="Wettkampfname" CssClass="text-danger" ErrorMessage="Bitte Wettkampfname eingeben." />
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="Teilnehmeranzahl" placeholder="Teilnehmeranzahl" CssClass="form-control" TextMode="SingleLine" />
                                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ControlToValidate="Teilnehmeranzahl" CssClass="text-danger" ErrorMessage="Bitte Wettkampfname." />
                                        <asp:CompareValidator runat="server" Operator="DataTypeCheck" CssClass="text-danger" Type="Integer" ControlToValidate="Teilnehmeranzahl" ErrorMessage="Die Anzahl muss eine Zahl sein" />
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="Strasse" placeholder="Strasse" CssClass="form-control" TextMode="SingleLine" />
                                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ControlToValidate="Strasse" CssClass="text-danger" ErrorMessage="Bitte Strasse eingeben." />
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="Ort" placeholder="Ort" CssClass="form-control" TextMode="SingleLine" />
                                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ControlToValidate="Ort" CssClass="text-danger" ErrorMessage="Bitte Strasse eingeben." />
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="Hausnummer" placeholder="Hausnummer" CssClass="form-control" TextMode="SingleLine" />
                                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ControlToValidate="Hausnummer" CssClass="text-danger" ErrorMessage="Bitte Hausnummer eingeben." />
                                        <asp:CompareValidator runat="server" Operator="DataTypeCheck" CssClass="text-danger" Type="Integer" ControlToValidate="Hausnummer" ErrorMessage="Die Hausnummer muss eine Zahl sein" />
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="Zeit" placeholder="Zeit (hh:mm)" CssClass="form-control" TextMode="SingleLine" />
                                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ControlToValidate="Zeit" CssClass="text-danger" ErrorMessage="Bitte Strasse eingeben." />
                                        <asp:RegularExpressionValidator CssClass="text-danger" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Zeit Format in hh:mm" ValidationExpression="^(0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]|[0-9]):[0-5][0-9]$"  ControlToValidate="Zeit" />
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="Datum" placeholder="Datum" CssClass="form-control" TextMode="Date" />
                                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ControlToValidate="Datum" CssClass="text-danger" ErrorMessage="Bitte Strasse eingeben." />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-footer">
                                    <asp:Button Text="Save" OnClick="eventErstellen" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-primary"/>
                                    <asp:Button Text="Close" OnClick="Submit" runat="server" data-dismiss="modal" CssClass="btn btn-secondary"/>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </ContentTemplate>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#mySecondModal">
                Für Event eintragen
            </button>
            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <!--Modal-->
                    <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
                    <div class="modal fade" id="mySecondModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="mySecondModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                        <div class="modal-dialog">
                            <div class="modal-content">
                                <div class="modal-header">
                                    <h5 class="modal-title">Modal title</h5>
                                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                    </button>
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-body">

                                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlSubject" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="true">
                                        <asp:ListItem Text="<Select Subject>" Value="0" />
                                    </asp:DropDownList>

                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-footer">
                                    <asp:Button Text="Save" OnClick="eventEintragen" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-primary"/>
                                    <asp:Button Text="Close" OnClick="Submit" runat="server" data-dismiss="modal" CssClass="btn btn-secondary"/>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </ContentTemplate>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I suggest you learn about [validation groups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.validationgroup?view=netframework-4.8#examples)

Comment: @ADyson So has my problem something to do with the validation groups ? I will read it anyways. But just to make sure that I'm not going to focus only on the validation groups afterwards.

Comment: Well at the moment you aren't using separate validation groups for each modal, so everything is validated at once. If you put the fields and buttons into separate groups, one for each modal, then when a button is clicked only the fields in the same group as the button will be validated. Take a look at the example in that link I gave you